# Get ressource URI for foreign object in django in a serializer?

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

Supposing we have the following models:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

class Food(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have these models in ModelViewSets and registered them as URLs with Django Rest Framework. And they are accessible as ressource URI successfully, but I want to add field for Food that can return the Person ressource URI. I can hardcode it as follows but I need something better:

```py
class Food(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_person_uri(self):
        return f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/persons/{self.person.id}/"
```

Serializer is as follows:

```py
class FoodSerializer(serializers.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = ["person", "name", "get_person_uri"]
```

Where `get_person_uri` should take me directly to the parent person URI

Moreover, here is my View:

```py
class FoodViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FoodSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    model = serializer_class.Meta.model
    queryset = model.objects.all()
```

Here is how it is registered in urls.py:

```py
router.register(r"foods", FoodViewSet, basename="foods")
```

Expected JSON response:

```json
{
  "name" : "Orange",
  "person": 3,
  "person_uri": "http://example.com/api/person/3"
}
```

What solutions can you suggest?

Comment: Can you update your serializer?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield

Comment: @IainShelvington Tried what's offerred in the docs. It doesn't add anything; maybe it should work in a parent showing its children ressources URI, but does not show parent URI for a child?

Comment: @IainShelvington I added how I want my JSON response needs to be

Comment: @SamirAhmane remove `many=True` when linking from a child to a parent (a foreign key)

Comment: @IainShelvington Having the same problem, there is absolutely no error but the field doesn't show up.